# White pixels around custom navigation bar image

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

In my iOS 5+ app, I use a custom navigation bar image, with custom navbar buttons.

First of all, here is how I tell my app to use the images :

In `AppDelegate.m` :

```
UIImage *navBarImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Navbar"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBarImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

UIImage *barButton = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Nav-button"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 6, 0, 6)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:barButton forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

So, the images are used. Great. But, there are a couple of things happening :

• First, on my button, under the bottom corners, au few white pixels appear (they're not on the original image, that's for sure). I also use a custom back button, and same thing happens. This *seems* to be more visible under iOS 6 than iOS 5.

• When I open a modal VC, the navigation bar is "filled up to the status bar" with white pixels. Only for a modal VC.

Here are screenshots of the situation.

[image: iOS 5 - Main]

iOS 5 , main VC.

[image: iOS 5 - Modal]

iOS 5, modal VC.

[image: iOS 6 - Main]

iOS 6, main VC.

[image: iOS 6 - Modal]

iOS 6, modal VC.

So, what can I do ? The white pixels under the buttons are not highly visible (a bit more for the back button), but I really want a nice design for the app, and this doesn't contribute at all..

Concerning the modal VC, I can use a "rectangle" image, which could cover the white pixels, but again, regarding design consistency, I'd prefer to use only one navigation bar..

As always, any explanation / solution / hint is greatly appreciated ! ;)

Thanks.

---

EDIT :

I just noticed that under iOS 6, the white pixels on top of the navigation bar are rounded, as the navigation bars in iOS 6.. Strange.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm! just for testing purpose, can you download the following [sample image](http://cl.ly/2a0H3N3J123r1r1A1C1D) for a navigation bar background and try this image instead? Just let us now how it looks with this image.

I'm just guessing, but i suppose your image is not pixel perfect for the navigation bar dimensions! Probably a few pixels below the optimum height for the navigation bar.

Comment: Well, my images are 320x44 (@2x 640x89), when yours are 320x46 (@2x 640x92). I didn't even think of that.. Funny thing is your images come from a AppDesignVault theme right ? Mine too, but I must have cropped my psd wrong when editing them.. I'll correct that on my images. With yours, it's correct (I can see a grey pixel on the top left but I think it comes from the image). I think what corrected the problem is that in your image, the corners are "filled" with black whereas mines are "empty" (png transparency). Strange that in a standard VC they appear black, and white on a modal VC.. Thanks !

Comment: Oh, and by the way, I also checked my button image.. The white pixels **are in it**.. *Woah* was I tired.. Thanks for pointing in the right direction !

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, the navigation-bar images are from a AppDesignVault theme, so the credits go to AppDesignVault for that! Regarding the background of the navigation-bar image: maybe this is the way to go! instead of a transparent area a black fill color needs to be used.